# Conditionals Within Handlebars, Jquery, PHP and MySql

Tags: handlebars.js

I have some HTML/table data with a Handlebars template:

```
<div class="users">
    <script id="userlist" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <th>Username</th> 
                <th>Real Name</th> 
                <th>Email</th> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#each this}}     
                <tr>
                    <td>{{name}}</td>
                    <td>{{email}} {{lastName}}</td> 
                    <td>{{time}}</td> 
                </tr> 
                {{/each}} 
            </tbody> 
        </table> 
    </script> 
</div>
```

I want to find the most elegant/optimized way to conditionally identify a table row in order to highlight the row based on a value I am getting from my JSON.

This block of code gets the JSON from my PHP class:

```
$("#register").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        name = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),
        email = $form.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val(), 
        func  

    /* Send the data using post */
    var posting = $.post( 'controller.php', { name: name, email: email, func: 'register'  } );

    /* Put the results into a template */
    posting.done(function(data) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var userlist = Handlebars.compile( $("#userlist").html() );
        $(".users").html(userlist(data));
    }); /*end function */

});
```

I am able to see my list of data no problem. That works great. I feel I need to do a registerHelper or a registerPartial but not sure.

Comment: How do you know which one you want to hilight? Is there anything else in the JSON? Presumably you could use the email address as a unique identifier but an ID number might be prettier.

Comment: I would like to highlight the <tr> - the entire row based on a value i get from the JSON. So it would go from <tr> to <tr class=active> I am not sure how to add the 'class=active' based on a condition within handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a boolean property, say `active`, set on your objects that indicates an active row, then you'd just do something like this in your template:

```
{{#each this}}
<tr{{#if active}} class="active"{{/if}}>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{email}} {{lastName}}</td> 
    <td>{{time}}</td> 
</tr> 
{{/each}}
```

Comment: So close. That works, but ultimately I am hoping to evaluate a value from my JSON which would turn on the row. I am trying this: Handlebars.registerHelper('ifactive', function(block) {
       if (this.active == '0') {
           return block(this);
       } else {
           return block.inverse(this);
       }
   });

Comment: That helper should work with `{{#ifactive}}...{{else}}...{{/ifactive}}` if that's the way you want to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/H7f5p/